# How to shift (right) a substring inside a string?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have this string:

```
'0123456abcde78sdfnwjeabcde8923kasjsducuabcded999'
```

How can I move the substring `'abcde'` two characters to the right to produce:

```
'012345678abcdesdfnwje89abcde23kasjsducud9abcde99'
```

So this:

```
s = '0123456abcde78'
t = 'abcde'
n = 2  # (right shift)

Function(s, t, n)
```

Should give:

```
'012345678abcde'
```

Edge cases that can be safely ignored:

- fewer characters than shift amount following substring (`'abcde1'`)
- consecutive occurrences of the substring (`'abcdeabcde123'`)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the regex-equivalent of `replace` - [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```py
import re

s = "0123456abcde78sdfnwjeabcde8923kasjsducuabcded999"
t = 'abcde'
n = 2
print(re.sub(rf"({t})(.{{{n}}})", r"\2\1", s))
```

Gives:

```
012345678abcdesdfnwje89abcde23kasjsducud9abcde99
```

Explanation:

- pattern:

  - `(` - First matching group:

    - `{t}` - replaces `t` using f-strings - literally match the full substring.
  - `)` - End first group
  - `(` - Second matching group:

    - `.` - any character
    - `{{` - escaped curly braces in f-string - to denote number of repetitions.
    - `{n}` - f-string replacement of `n` - the number of repetitions.
    - `}}` - escaped closing braces.
  - `)` - End second group
- replacement:

  - Simply replace the order of the above groups.

[Demo and explanations (without the f-strings) in regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1CCFmg/2)

---

To do a left shift instead, just change the order of the groups (i.e. first match any `n` characters and then match `t`):

```py
re.sub(rf"(.{{{n}}})({t})", r"\2\1", s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new string according to the position of the index of the string you are looking for. Something among the following lines:

```
s = '0123456abcde78'
t = 'abcde'
n = 2  # (right shift)
tmp = s.index(t)
new_s = s[:tmp] + s[tmp+len(t):tmp+len(t)+n] + t + s[tmp+len(t)+n:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable, so you will have to create a new string from:

- the beginning up to the index of `t` in `s`
- `n` characters starting from the end of `t` (so at `s.index(t) + len(t))
- `t`
- the end of the string starting at `n` characters past the end of t

In Python is could be:

```
def function(s, t, n):
    ix = s.index(t)
    length = len(t)
    return s[:ix]+ s[ix + length: ix + length + n] + t + s[ix + length + n:]
```

Error and corner case handling are omitted per your requirement...